# Runtime error on Ideone but works fine on my computer

Tags: c, c89

I was writing a program for finding out Intersection of two sorted arrays in C language. The code works fine when I compile it with GCC on my machine and run it, but gives a runtime error on ideone.com.

Here is the [Live link](http://ideone.com/Fcd088) to the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int arr1[] = {1,3,4,5,7,11,123};
    int arr2[] = {2,3,5,6,7,8,9,11,23,123};

    int i, j=0, k=0, l1, l2;

    l1 = sizeof(arr1)/ sizeof(arr1[0]);
    l2 = sizeof(arr2)/ sizeof(arr2[0]);

    while(j<l1 && k<l2){
        if(arr1[j]<arr2[k]){
            j++;
        }
        else if(arr1[j]>arr2[k]){
            k++;
        }
        else{
            printf("%d\t", arr1[j]);
            j++; k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your ideone link doesn't show any runtime error. Are you ure this is the code that gave you runtime error?

Comment: @BlueMoon yes, it was showing for me.

Comment: If it works with GCC, this kind of seems like a ideone.com problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very sure, as your code looks good.

However, adding a `return 0;` at the end of `main()` gives a success. Maybe, a constrain with the on-line compiler itself.

<sup>Also, changed `int main()` to `int main(void)`, but that is of no importance here.</sup>

see <kbd>[LIVE CODE](http://ideone.com/MYJKEZ)</kbd>

Comment: Adding `return 0;` is only necessary in C89.